# What is steady state current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

I am currently trying to understand the following paper:

```
On the nonlinear electromagnetic coupling between a coil and an
oscillating magnet
```

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/43/29/295005/meta

It is very interesting, but I am having troubles to understand how they calculated, or what they meant exactly when they write:

> For each oscillation point, the steady-state voltage across the
>   load resistor was measured, thus allowing the amplitudes of the ﬁrst four
>   harmonics of the forcing frequency to be determined.

My question is:

**What do they mean by "steady state" ?** 
The voltage is constantly changing when the magnet is moving in the coil.

Comment: I haven't read the paper at the link but, typically, steady state means that any transients have decayed to insignificance and the response is just that due to the forcing function.